# UDF executing multiple times with Structured References

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I am experiencing performance problems with a large (wide and long) table that uses a UDF that has variables passed as structured references.

It seems that when a structured reference for a specific cell, eg "[@A]" is passed to the UDF, it flags the whole column, ie "[A]" as dirty and every cell in the column the UDF references is recalculated (this is the source of the performance problem).

I have found that if I change the UDF within the table to use cell address, eg "A2", then the UDF only executes when that cell changes.

To test, create a simple function with debug.print to highlight when it is run:

```
Public Function zap(a As Double, b As Double) As Double
    Debug.Print "zap: " & a & "+" & b
    zap = a + b
End Function
```

Create a 3 column table (A, B, C), with column C as "=zap([@A],[@B])".  if you enter or change a value in column A or B, the UDF will execute for each row regardless of whether the value in the row/column intersection has changed.

if you change column C to use cell addressing, eg  "=zap(A2,B2)", then the UDF only executes once for the row that has changed.

I can use cell addressing to overcome the performance problem, however using a table with structured references provide a lot of benefits for this application.

I would like to know if I have missed or misunderstood something about structured references, or whether there is an adjustment to the UDF that can accommodate.

Comment: Try using `=@zap([@A],[@B])`

Comment: @Rory - interesting... but yes. That should be an answer.

Comment: Thank you Rory - that worked!

Comment: @Rory Do you have any explanation at hand for that behavior?

Comment: I'd guess it's a side effect of the dynamic arrays. Whether MS view it as a bug or a feature, who knows? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to Rory - placing an @ at the beginning of the formula worked:

```
=@zap([@A],[@B])
```

Update:

In putting this into practice, I also found that should any of the dependent variables be based on formulas (eg, if [@A] contained a formula), then this will need an "@" at the front as well.

In my circumstance, there are so many dependencies it was easier to place an "@" at in front of every formula in the table (my new 'rule' when working with UDFs and Tables). Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I used this formula in column C `=zap([@A],[@B])` and as you can see in the video below I cannot reproduce your issue. It only re-calculates the formula in the row I changed something.

[image]

Comment: Weird. I can repro the issue. What version of Excel? Or maybe this is a general setting somewhere...

Comment: @BigBen Office 2019 Pro 64Bit Edition (Version 2201 Build 14827.20158)

Comment: Ok. I repro-ed in O365. Then was digging through the options to see if one of them might be causing the issue. Hopefully more people will respond to the thread with whether or not they can repro.

Comment: thank you for taking a look at this - for reference, the problem is occurring on O365, Version 2102 Build 13801.21106